# Python 2, ConfigParser: retrieving the line number of a section/option

Tags: python, configparser

Is there a way in the Package "ConfigParser" to obtain the line-number in which the Parser had read a specific section or key?

### INI-File

```
[section1]
    option1=3
    option2=4
[section2]
    option3=right
```

i.e. a method that returns the line-number for section1 (lineNo 1) or for option3 (lineNo 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know python's ConfigParser does not keep track of line numbers.

You can convince yourself by reading the source code. Here the link to the source code of `ConfigParser` from python 2.7.9: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Lib/ConfigParser.py

And the source code in python 3.4 (the most current commit at the time of writing): https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/516d3773ecb2/Lib/configparser.py

Reading a file is done by either `read()` or `readfp()`. Both are just wrappers around `_read()`. The method `_read()` does keep track of the line number in the variable `lineno` but as far as I can tell `lineno` is only used to report error.

---

Here is an overview of alternative config parsers: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout

From a quick search it seems that only [INITools](http://pythonpaste.org/initools/) keeps track of line numbers.

I do not know how current the information in the wiki is.